# ajaxSubmit enables disabled fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have some disabled=true  fields,
but then I submit a form using ajaxSubmit(), all disabled fields become enabled. What I have to do to keep fields disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that within the `success` callback option, e.g.:

```
var options = {
    url:         '/some/url',
    type:        'post',
    target:       '#resultsDiv',
    success:       function() { $("#foo").attr("disabled","disabled");  }
};
```